# getting text from li with jquery

Tags: jquery

transitioning from javascript to jquery. problem getting text from li and sending it to input using jquery- well the click call is working but not the rest.

HTML:

```
<ul id="cssmenu">
<li><span>Text1 Text Text</span></li>
<li><span>Text Text Text</span></li>
<li><span>sheh</span></li>
<li><span>Text Text Text</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="ches">
```

this is my **working** half jquery half vanilla JS:

```
 $("#cssmenu li").click(function(li){
    document.getElementById("ches").value = this.textContent;})
```

why is this **not** working:

```
$("#cssmenu li").click(function(li){
$("#ches").value = this.textContent;})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$("#ches").value = this.textContent;}
```

use:

```
$("#ches").val(this.textContent);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DGPun/)**

You can't use `value` on a jQuery object; use `.val()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You need use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("#ches").val(this.textContent);
```

OR

```
 $("#ches").val($(this).text());
```

instead of

```
$("#ches").value = this.textContent;
```